# How to drop data above a certain frequency in a histogram/dataset?

Tags: python, histogram

To make things clearer, I don't want to remove the entire bin from the histogram, I just want to get rid of some of the data so that it is brought below a desired frequency. The line in the image shows the max frequency I would like

[image: Line shows desired frequency]

For context, I have a dataset containing a number of angles. My question is very similar to the question asked here [Remove data above threshold in histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51311048/remove-data-above-threshold-in-histogram) in terms of the data used but unlike the question in the link, I dont wish to get rid of the data, just reduce it.

Can I do this directly from the histogram or will I need to just delete some of the data in the dataset?

edit (sorry I am new to coding and formatting here):
here is a solution i tried

```
bns = 30
hist, bins  = np.histogram(dataset['Steering'], bins= bns)
removeddata = []

spb = 700
for j in range(bns):
    rdata = []
    for i in range(len(dataset['Steering'])):
        if dataset['Steering'][i] >= bins[j] and dataset['Steering'][i] <= 
        bins[j+1]:
            rdata.append(i)
    rdata = shuffle(rdata)
    rdata = rdata[spb:]
    removeddata.extend(rdata)


print('removed:', len(removeddata))
dataset.drop(dataset.index[removeddata], inplace = True)
print ('remaining:', len(dataset))



center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])*0.5
plt.bar(center,hist,width=0.05)
plt.show()
```

This is somebody else's solution but it seemed to work for them. Even directly copying, it still throws errors. The error I got was "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()", I tried to change 'and' to & and got the error "TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]". Unsure what this exactly refers to but points to the line with the if statement. Checked the dtype of everything and they are all type float64, so unsure of my next step

Comment: Sounds like you want a low-pass filter?

Comment: Thanks but no, I don't think so, the angles in question are steering angles. With reference to the link I provided, I basically have the exact same set up as the user who asked the question, but the user who provided an answer has interpreted the question differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution takes into account the clarified requirement that the original input data that exceeds the frequency threshold be dropped.  I left my other answer because it is simpler and different enough that it may be useful to another user.

To clarify, this answer produces a new 1D array of data with fewer elements and then plots a histogram from that new data.  The data are shuffled before the elements are removed (in case the input data were pre-sorted) in order to prevent bias in dropping data from either the low or high side of each bin.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import shuffle


def remove_gated_val_recursive(idx, to_gate_lst, bins_lst, data_lst):
    if to_gate_lst[idx] == 0:
        return(data_lst)
    else:
        bin_min, bin_max = bins_lst[idx], bins_lst[idx + 1]
        for i in range(len(data_lst)):
            if bin_min <= data_lst[i] < bin_max:
                del data_lst[i]
                to_gate_lst[idx] -= 1
                break
        return remove_gated_val_recursive(idx, to_gate_lst, bins_lst, data_lst)

    
threshold = 80

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title("Some data")

np.random.seed(30)
data = np.random.randn(1000)

num_bins = 23

raw_hist, raw_bins = np.histogram(data, num_bins)

to_gate = []
for i in range(len(raw_hist)):
    if raw_hist[i] > threshold:
        to_gate.append(raw_hist[i] - threshold)
    else:
        to_gate.append(0)

data_lst = list(data)
shuffle(data_lst)

for idx in range(len(raw_hist)):
    remove_gated_val_recursive(idx, to_gate, raw_bins, data_lst)
    
new_data = np.array(data_lst)
hist, bins = np.histogram(new_data, num_bins)

width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) * 0.5
ax1.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)

plt.show()
```

gives the following histogram, plotted from the `new_data` array.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, thanks a lot. The only issue is that my data means the error: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" is thrown, but there is a way around this which I will share when I get there

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't re-bin or re-center the data, but I believe it generally achieves what you're asking.  Working from the example in the chosen answer of the post you linked, I edit the `hist` array so that the original input data is not changed as you indicated is your preferred solution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1.set_title("Some data")
ax2.set_title("Gated data < threshold")

np.random.seed(10)
data = np.random.randn(1000)

num_bins = 23
avg_samples_per_bin = 200

hist, bins = np.histogram(data, num_bins)
width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) * 0.5
ax1.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)

threshold = 80

gated = np.empty([len(hist)], dtype=np.int64)
for i in range(len(hist)):
    if hist[i] > threshold:
        gated[i] = threshold
    else:
        gated[i] = hist[i]

ax2.bar(center, gated, align="center", width=width)

plt.show()
```

which gives

[image: Gated histogram]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is generally what I am looking for in the histogram, but I forgot to make it clear that I wanted the new dataset to become what is being displayed in the new histogram. I.e all the data that would have been restricted can now be removed from the original input such that I could plot the histogram as normal. I am sorry I didn't make this clear enough, its late for me but I appreciate the help. I have edited my main question to show a solution I tried from somebody else with the same problem and which errors I got